# How to create an array of ActiveX Comboboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to dynamically add to an excel worksheet a several activex comboboxes, whose number and content depends on other data previously set. I want to store them into an array to manage their contents afterwards (in the same worksheet there will be other comboboxes with different purpose). I run the following code:

```
Sub run_Combo_Test()

    Dim DestinationBookmarkCombo() As Object
    Dim i, k As Integer
    Dim nCombos, nHeaderLines, nOptions As Integer

    nCombos = 5
    nOptions = 4
    nHeaderLines = 3

    ReDim DestinationBookmarkCombo(0 To nCombos - 1) As Object
    For i = 0 To nCombos - 1
        Set DestinationBookmarkCombo(i) = Worksheets("bula").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=50, Top:=80, Width:=100, _
                Height:=15)
        With DestinationBookmarkCombo(i)
        With .Object
            .Left = xlApp.Worksheets("bula").Cells(nHeaderLines + 1 + i, 4).Left
            .Top = xlApp.Worksheets("bula").Cells(nHeaderLines + 1 + i, 4).Top
            .Placement = 1
            For k = 1 To nOptions
                .AddItem "Option " + CStr(k)
            Next k
            .Name = "Combo_" + CStr(i)
            '.OnAction = "myCombo_Change"
        End With
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

The code generates a single empty combobox and returns an "object required" error. I'm not able to track where the problem is. Can someone help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just needed to add ".Object" in front of AddItem. It's tough to debug this kind of thing because VBA doesn't want to allow breakpoints or stepping when adding user interface objects on the fly.

```
Option Explicit

Sub run_Combo_Test()

Dim DestinationBookmarkCombo() As Object
Dim i, k As Integer
Dim nCombos, nHeaderLines, nOptions As Integer

nCombos = 3
nOptions = 4
nHeaderLines = 3

ReDim DestinationBookmarkCombo(0 To nCombos - 1)

For i = 0 To nCombos - 1
    Set DestinationBookmarkCombo(i) = Worksheets("bula").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
            Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=50, Top:=80, Width:=100, _
            Height:=15)
    DestinationBookmarkCombo(i).Left = Worksheets("bula").Cells(nHeaderLines + 1 + i, 4).Left
    DestinationBookmarkCombo(i).Top = Worksheets("bula").Cells(nHeaderLines + 1 + i, 4).Top
    DestinationBookmarkCombo(i).Placement = 1
    For k = 1 To nOptions
        DestinationBookmarkCombo(i).Object.AddItem "Option " & CStr(k)
    Next k
    DestinationBookmarkCombo(i).Name = "Combo_" + CStr(i)
Next i


End Sub
```